# Apply a filter to the value of a variable using backticks

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, command-substitution

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but reading about this issue on the internet has proven fruitless. I'm trying to better understand the grave/backtick operator and I've been doing okay so far except on one occasion.

Suppose I have a bash script and a variable in it, like so:

```
var=`ls -al | grep '^...x'
```

Now, the script requires the user to enter something and based on what that something is, it outputs a result. So, without boring you with the full script, I want to boil it down to one question. If the user inputs "-t" as an argument, the script needs to print all the .txt files that can be executed by the user, i.e, something like:

```
$var | grep '\.txt$'
```

Now, the problem arises when I try to reassign the value of var. I tried doing:

```
var=`$var | grep '\.txt$'`
```

but this doesn't work. I am not sure what I'm missing here, what is the proper way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try moving away from the back tick operators for executing commands. Not as portable as using something along the lines of the following:

```
$ my_var=$(ls -la | grep '^...x')
```

In regards to your problem, try

```
$ var=$(echo $var | grep '\.txt$')
```

Comment: i code my scripts with these as much as i can (almost always)

Answer (score 0):

The stuff inside the backticks (it's called [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), by the way) is a command to be executed. When you write

```
$var | grep '\.txt$'
```

this executes the value of `var` as a command. That's not what you want: you want to pass the value as input to the `grep` command. That's basically

```
echo "$var" | grep '\.txt$'
```

so the assignment would be

```
var=`echo "$var" | grep '\.txt$'`
```

I recommend using the dollar-parenthesis syntax instead of the backticks, because the quoting rules are easier to understand, especially with nested substitutions: a command substitution started with `$(` extends to the matching `)`.

```
var="$(echo "$var" | grep '\.txt$')"
```

Note the double quotes around `$var`. The syntax `$var` only means “the value of `var`” inside double quotes; outside double quotes, it's more complicated. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more information.

Beware that [parsing the output of `ls` is usually a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It mangles some file names and is rarely the simplest way. If you want to list only `.txt` files, simply use the wildcard pattern `*.txt` (this excludes dot files, unlike `ls -al`; to include them, add the pattern `.*.txt`). If you want to consider only the ones that are executable, a robust way is to process them in a loop:

```
for x in *.txt; do
  if [ -x "$x" ]; then
    … do stuff
  fi
done
```